# Inkscape: Why is the path so complex after path division?

Tags: inkscape, path

[image]

Steps:

1. create 2 circles and center them.
2. select both and `path` > `division`
3. use the `edit path by nodes` tool to inspect the path

**Why is the path so complex in step 3? Is there a way to simplify that?**

---

I've tried `path` > `simplify`, but it turned out to be a little different.
(I simplify the red one, and the gray one remains the same)
[image]

[image: A closer look at step 3]
[image]

Comment: Related bug report: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/471

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why exactly 'Path → Division' creates more nodes than strictly necessary, but it does seem like it's the intended behavior. If I had to guess, the Inkscape developers may have done this for extra accuracy.

In this case, you can get pretty much the same output, but with simpler paths by duplicating the inner circle (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>) and using 'Path → Difference' instead.

Comment: uhmmm  not really intended behaiviopur its long standing  known bug  that needs fixing .
there is a workaround to use LPE bool operations that uses different algorithm that does not have this problem

Comment: @AdamBelis When I read the [related bug report](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/471), it sounded to me like it was a deliberate trade-off for accuracy, but maybe I've misunderstood the situation.

Comment: yes and no.  fix was a comprise real solution would  behave like one would expect. there are a one dev how is slowli working on  back end of bool operations to get it work but it can take time

Answer (score 2):

This is a known Bug.
you have two options
A. Use LPE BOOLEAN operations

1. prepare your bool operation objects
2. copy top object
3. select bottom object and open path/path effect dialog
4. add effect LPE Bollean operation
5. click past selected object button
6. change mode to division
7. you can keep it non destructive or convert it to the shape

B.
simplify  your result with LPE simplify